# How can I remove specific configuration file listed on "vctl config list platform.driver"?

Tags: python, modbus, volttron

On running the command **vctl config list platform.driver** , I get the configuration for fake device agent and my remote agent. It must be because I choose "Yes" for installing fake device on the master driver on running **vcfg** initially.

Can anyone suggest me how to remove the fake device only keeping the configuration for my modbus device agent??

I tried removing the platform.driver ***vctl remove platform.driver*** and reconfiguring my VOLTTRON environment. (this time without installing fake device) Still, I am getting the config listed for both the devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below command to delete a specific configuration by name from the store

```
volttron-ctl config delete <agent vip identity> <configuration name>
```

https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/6.0/core_services/config_store/Commandline-Interface.html